# Embedding a Read Only twitter feed widget into SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've got a SharePoint 2010 Intranet and am able to embed a twitter feed widget successfully. However we have a requirement to render the feed in a read only format so that users are unable to follow any links presented from the widgets and feed items.

Would be interested in knowing the simplest approach needed in order to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something as simple as cancelling "click" actions in the respective container?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myLinkID').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
   }); 
});
```